# JavaScript inserting images

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to insert specific images on specific pages when each pages loads and i just cant seem to get it, my code looks like this

```
function display() {
coursetitle = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
coursecode = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("code")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
enrolledyear = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
semester = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("semester")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
labday = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("labday")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
lectureday = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("lectureday")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
description = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
graphic = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("graphic")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

 document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Title: " + coursetitle + "<br />Code: " + 
+ coursecode + "<br />Year: " + enrolledyear + "<br />Semester:" + semester +
"<br />Lab Day:" + labday + "<br />Lecture Day:" + lectureday +
"<br />Course Description:<br/>" + description;
```

What should i do?

Comment: What kind of HTML are you using to have weird tags like `<labday>`?

Comment: @Kolink I think code is parsing xml, not html

Answer (score 0):

If graphic value has the image path

```
 document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Title: " + coursetitle + "<br />Code: " + 
+ coursecode + "<br />Year: " + enrolledyear + "<br />Semester:" + semester +
"<br />Lab Day:" + labday + "<br />Lecture Day:" + lectureday +
"<br />Course Description:<br/>" + description + "</br> <img src=\""+graphic +"\" /> ";
```